# How to create a new nested list in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested-lists

I'm trying to transalte all Es and Bs in a user input to a binary sequence. For example if the input is "i am BBEBE years old, my son is BBE" I want to both replace the E/B's in that string with placeholder numbers, and store the EB numbers in a nested list.
So my list would look like EB_to_01 = [[1,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0]] .

```
userinput = str(input(''))
    newstring1 = ''
    EB_to_01 = []
    placeholder = 0
    y = 0

    while y < len(userinput) :

        for i in userinput[y:] :
            if i != 'E' and i != 'B' :
                newstring1 += (i)
                y += 1
            else : break

        placeholder += 1
        sub_list = []

        for i in userinput[y:]:
            if i == 'E' :
                newstring1 += str(placeholder)
                sub_list.append(0) # replace 0 with i to add BE_to_01 function
                y += 1
            elif i == 'B' :
                newstring1 += str(placeholder)
                sub_list.append(1) # replace 1 with i to add BE_to_01 function
                y += 1
            else :
                EB_to_01.append(sub_list)
                break
```

So far my code completely disregards the second sequence of EB's and nests the first 5 times. What I am looking for is [[1,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0]]

My whole code looks like this:

```
def decode(userinput) :

    userinput = str(input(''))
    newstring1 = ''
    EB_to_01 = []
    placeholder = 0
    y = 0

    while y < len(userinput) :

        for i in userinput[y:] :
            if i != 'E' and i != 'B' :
                newstring1 += (i)
                y += 1
            else : break

        placeholder += 1
        sub_list = []

        for i in userinput[y:]:
            if i == 'E' :
                newstring1 += str(placeholder)
                sub_list.append(0)
                y += 1
            elif i == 'B' :
                newstring1 += str(placeholder)
                sub_list.append(1)
                y += 1
            else :
                EB_to_01.append(sub_list)
                break


    final_output = ''
    a = 1

    for i in newstring1:
        if i.isdigit() :
            b = 1
            for x in EB_to_01 :
                if b == a:
                    u = str(int("".join(str(x) for i in x), 2))
                    final_output += u
                else:
                    b += 1
        else:
            final_output += i
            a += 1
    

    return final_output

print(decode(userinput=str))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel, if you are looking for string patterns, just use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/).

```
import re

map_dic = {'B': 1, 'E': 0}
pattern = r'[BE]+'

test_str = "i am BBEBE years old, my son is BBE"

BEs = re.findall(pattern, test_str)
# ['BBEBE', 'BBE']

dec_BEs = [[map_dic[char] for char in BE] for BE in BEs]

print(dec_BEs)
# [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```